# Content-Security-Policy (CSP): how to allow svg image in object

Tags: javascript, svg, configuration, content-security-policy, data-uri

I am using the js plugin that adds inside itself SVG images.
I have added CSP policy to my website, but I can't configure it to allow plugin's code.

Its code looks like:

```
label=$("<object style='height:10px; width:10px;' type='image/svg+xml' data='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8," +
"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">" +
"<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" some parameters/>"+
"<text>SomeText</text></svg>'></object>");
el.html(label)
```

I am looking for a configuration that allows SVG image that is rendered in the object.
I am tried different options from there - [CSP: object-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/object-src).

But I am alway get error like next:

> Refused to load plugin data from 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, my svg here' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'unsafe-eval'".

How to configure CSP correct in this case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That SVG image is provided by a `data:` URL, so your policy must be updated to allow that.

You don’t show your current policy or where you’re setting it, but assuming you’re setting it with the `Content-Security-Policy` header and it currently has `object-src 'unsafe-eval'`, then you can allow `data:` URLs there by updating that part of the policy to look like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: object-src data: 'unsafe-eval'
```

That shows just the relevant part of the current policy in the `Content-Security-Policy` header. Whatever other directives you currently have in that header value, you’d want to preserve as-is.

Comment: It should be noted that this opens the page up for an attack vector for any item on the page using object-src data.  If your goal is security you'd be better off using a sha hash of the script trying to be executed rather than opening up this hole.

Comment: @Chris what's the mechanism to do an SHA hash, to include in the CSS? If the original is `background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2220%22%20height%3D%2220%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccircle%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke%3D%22%23e5e5e5%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%20cx%3D%2210%22%20cy%3D%2210%22%20r%3D%227%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A");`, should I just so an SHA of the text there?

Answer (score 17):

I recently came across this same issue and was able to get around it by adding:

```
Content-Security-Policy: img-src data: w3.org/svg/2000
```

Comment: great! any reference? do you know if it has good browser support? (eg it doesn't cause issues)

Comment: It's been working fine for me so far, but I know that's not a very scientific answer :-)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't allowing all "data:"?

Comment: This is allowing loading images from w3.org/svg/2000 and loading resources via the [data URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Agreed with @stoicalpirate, remove the `w3.org/svg/200`. You only need `data:` in the CSP to get it to work.

Comment: This allows the both all `data:` sources and the `w3.org/svg/2000` source.

Comment: Where is that code to be added?