# How to allow external images referenced within embedded SVG?

Tags: html, image, svg, content-security-policy

On https://www.gamepro.de there's an SVG embedded in the HTML code which references an image from another domain via a `<use>` element like this:

```svg
<svg id="header-ivwbrand" alt="Partner von GameStar">
  <use xlink:href="https://static.cgames.de/gp_cb/assets/core/images/icons.svg#gs_logo"></use>
</svg>
```

Though this causes a security error. In Firefox it says

> Security Error: Content at https://www.gamepro.de/ may not load data from https://static.cgames.de/gp_cb/assets/core/images/icons.svg.

In Chrome the message is

> Unsafe attempt to load URL https://static.cgames.de/gp_cb/assets/core/images/icons.svg from frame with URL https://www.gamepro.de/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Unfortunately, both messages are not very informative. I assume a `Content-Security-Policy` header needs to be set to allow embedding the image that way, though the [CSP specification](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/) isn't clear on which directive covers that.

Trying around by setting it to `object-src www.gamepro.de` or `object-src 'unsafe-eval'` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414538/432681 don't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly you can't do cross-origin requests from a `<use>` element.  The `<use>` would need to add support for a `crossorigin` attribute.  In SVG2 that [has been added for `<image>` elements](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#embedded-ImageElementCrossoriginAttribute), but not yet the `<use>` element.

[More useful information here](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch10-cors.html)

Comment: Thank you! I natually expected the cross-origin logic to work everywhere. Sad that it doesn't yet and that browsers don't provide clear hints about this circumstance. I dug a bit more into this now and saw that there's [an open issue for that on the SVG spec.](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/707) and [one for adding a `crossorigin` modifier, among others, to CSS](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1603).

Comment: Read about a possible workaround -  [Ajaxing for your SVG Sprite](https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/).