# Unable to display icons due to CSP

Tags: reactjs, svg, content-security-policy

In my React application I'm having trouble displaying an icon from the `vsc` module because of CSP:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://ww/… (“default-src”).
```

My Content Security Policy looks like:

```
default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; font-src https://static.skyassets.com data:; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'self' data:;4
```

Whereas the HTML is:

```
<button class="css-m8wrzs"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="css-xxyih9" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 2v1.67l-5 4.759V14H6V8.429l-5-4.76V2h14z"></path></svg></button>
```

With the `.css-xxyih9` being:

```
fill: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><linearGradient id='lgm3ufb5'><stop offset='0' stop-color='%235888cf'/><stop offset='1' stop-color='%231155bb'/></linearGradient></svg>#lgm3ufb5");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Multiple CSPs? As you have defined img-src, it seems it is using a CSP with fallback to default-src for images. Check meta tags and response headers. Content needs to pass all CSPs present.

Comment: There a single CSP that's the one above

Comment: Restring to guessing... It is perhaps not treated as an image. Try adding data: to default-src and check if it passes. If it does, then try to figure out which directive it fits, it could be media-src or object-src. The answer by stoicalpirate at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408595/content-security-policy-csp-how-to-allow-svg-image-in-object could also be helpful.